# Images are displayed in the format "text/html"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angular

I can not find where the error is and I decided to completely lay out the client and server code. But most likely a bug somewhere in Rails. The essence of the error lies in the fact that the photos are displayed in the format `text/html`. Error:

> GET http://localhost:4200/photos/original/missing.png 404 (Not Found)

I'll start from the server:

> rails 5.1.6 api:

To display the image I use gem "paperclip". I'm using the Oracle database. Photos are stored in BLOB format. Where could  make a mistake here?

photos_controller.rb:

```
class PhotosController < ApplicationController

  def index
    @photos = Photo.all

    array = @photos.map do |photo|
      photo_push = {
        l_users_id:      photo.l_users_id,
        photo:           photo.photo.url
      }

      photo_push
    end

    render json: array
  end

  private

  def photo_params
    params.permit(
      :l_users_id, 
      :photo
    )
  end

end
```

photo.rb:

```
class Photo < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.primary_key = "l_users_id"


  belongs_to :user

  has_attached_file :photo
  validates_attachment_content_type :photo, content_type: ["image/jpg", "image/jpeg", "image/png"]

end
```

routes.rb:

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :users, only: [:index, :create, :update, :destroy]
  resources :photos, only: [:index]
  mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth'
end
```

> angular 4.4.6:

`authService.currentUserData` is needed to display the data of the current user.

component:

```
import { Component, OnInit} from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from "../../../services/auth/auth.service";
import { PhotoService} from "../../../services/photo/photo.service";
import { Photo} from "../../../models/photo.model";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-profile',
  templateUrl: './profile.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./profile.component.scss'],
  providers: [PhotoService]
})

export class ProfileComponent implements OnInit {

  photos: Array<Photo> ;

  filteredPhotos = [];

  constructor(
    protected authService: AuthService,
    private servPhoto: PhotoService
  ) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.loadPhotos();
  }

  private loadPhotos() {
    this.servPhoto.getPhotos().subscribe(
      photo => {
        if (!this.authService.currentUserData) {
          return;
        }
        this.photos = photo;
        this.filteredPhotos = this.photos.filter(
          (photo) => photo.l_users_id == this.authService.currentUserData.user_id
        );
      }
    )
  }

}
```

html:

```
<div class="container-fluid" *ngIf="authService.currentUserData">
  <div class="card card-profile">
    <div class="card-avatar">
      <a>
        <img 
          class="img" 
          *ngFor="let photo of filteredPhotos" 
          src="{{ photo?.photo }}">
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

model:

```
export class Photo{
    constructor(
        public l_users_id: number,
        public photo: Blob
    ) { }
}
```

service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AuthService } from '../auth/auth.service';

@Injectable()
export class PhotoService {
  constructor(
    private _authService: AuthService
  ) {}

  getPhotos() {
    return this._authService.get('photos')
      .map(result => result.json())
  }

}
```

At the moment, I have displayed everything that I have in the code associated with "Photos" (except for modules in the angular). What have I done wrong or what have I missed?

AuthService:

```
import {Injectable, Optional} from "@angular/core";
import {CanActivate, CanLoad, Router, ActivatedRoute} from "@angular/router";
import {
  AuthOptions, AuthData, UserData, RegisterData, SignInData, UpdatePasswordData,
  ResetPasswordData
} from "../../models/auth.model";
import {Http, Response, RequestOptionsArgs, RequestMethod, RequestOptions, Headers, Request} from "@angular/http";
import {Observable, Subject} from "rxjs";


@Injectable()
export class AuthService implements CanActivate, CanLoad {


  get currentUserData(): UserData {
    return this.atCurrentUserData;
  }

  private atCurrentUserData: UserData;
  private _authOptions: AuthOptions;
  private _authData: AuthData;
  private _userData: any;
  private _authDataInterval: any;

  constructor(private _http: Http,
              @Optional() private _activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute,
              @Optional() private _router: Router) {
  }

  //--------------------------------------------Public Methods----------------------------------------------------------

  canActivate(): boolean {
    if (this.userSignedIn())
      return true;
    else {
      if (this._authOptions.signInStoredUrlStorageKey) {
        this._authOptions.dataStorage.setItem(
          this._authOptions.signInStoredUrlStorageKey,
          window.location.pathname + window.location.search
        );
      }

      if (this._router && this._authOptions.signInRedirect)
        this._router.navigate([this._authOptions.signInRedirect]);

      return false;
    }
  }

  canLoad(): boolean {
    return this.canActivate()
  }

  get userData(): any {
    if (this._userData)
      return this._userData;
    else
      return {
        user_id: 0,
        provider: '',
        uid: '',
        name: '',
        login: '',
        email: ''
      }
  }

  get waitUserData(): Observable<boolean> {
    return Observable.create(observer => {
      if (this._userData) {
        observer._next(true);
        observer.complete();
      } else {
        if (this.userSignedIn()) {
          let interval = setInterval(() => {
            if (this._userData) {
              clearInterval(interval);
              observer._next(true);
              observer.complete();
            }
          }, 100)
        } else {
          observer.complete();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  get authData(): AuthData {
    return this._authData;
  }

  init(options?: AuthOptions) {
    let defaultAuthOptions: AuthOptions = {
      apiPath: null,
      apiSignInPath: 'auth/sign_in',
      signInPath: '',
      signInRedirect: null,
      signInStoredUrlStorageKey: null,
      dataStorage: localStorage,
      apiSignOutPath: 'auth/sign_out',
      signOutFailedValidate: false,

      apiValidateTokenPath: 'auth/validate_token',

      apiDeleteAccountPath: 'auth',
      apiRegisterAccountPath: 'auth',
      registerAccountCallbackPath: window.location.href,

      apiUpdatePasswordPath: 'auth',
      apiResetPasswordPath: 'auth/password',
      resetPasswordCallbackPath: window.location.href,
      oAuthBase: window.location.origin,
      oAuthPaths: {
        github: 'auth/github'
      },

      oAuthCallbackPath: 'auth_callback',
      oAuthWindowType: 'newWindow',
      oAuthWindowOptions: null,

      globalOptions: {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json',
          'Accept': 'application/json'
        }
      },
      authDataChecking: false,
      authDataCheckingInterval: 5000,
      userDataClass: null
    };

    this._authOptions = (<any>Object).assign(defaultAuthOptions, options);

    this._loadAuthData();
    this._processAuthDataChecking();
  }

  userSignedIn(): boolean {
    return !!this._authData;
  }

  registerAccount(registerData: RegisterData): Observable<Response> {
    registerData['password_confirmation'] = registerData['passwordConfirmation'];
    delete registerData['passwordConfirmation'];

    registerData['confirm_success_url'] = this._authOptions.registerAccountCallbackPath;

    return this.post(this._authOptions.apiRegisterAccountPath, JSON.stringify(registerData));
  }

  deleteAccount(): Observable<Response> {
    return this.delete(this._authOptions.apiDeleteAccountPath);
  }

  signIn(signInData: SignInData): Observable<Response> {
    let body = JSON.stringify({
      login: signInData.login,
      email: signInData.email,
      password: signInData.password
    });

    let observ = this.post(this._authOptions.apiSignInPath, body);
    observ.subscribe(res => this.atCurrentUserData = res.json().data, _error => null);

    return observ;
  }


  signInOAuth(oAuthType: string) {
    let oAuthPath: string = this._getOAuthPath(oAuthType);
    let callbackUrl: string = `${window.location.origin}/${this._authOptions.oAuthCallbackPath}`;
    let oAuthWindowType: string = this._authOptions.oAuthWindowType;
    let authUrl: string = this._getOAuthUrl(oAuthPath, callbackUrl, oAuthWindowType);

    if (oAuthWindowType == 'newWindow') {
      let oAuthWindowOptions = this._authOptions.oAuthWindowOptions;
      let windowOptions = '';

      if (oAuthWindowOptions) {
        for (let key in oAuthWindowOptions) {
          windowOptions += `,${key}=${oAuthWindowOptions[key]}`;
        }
      }

      let popup = window.open(
        authUrl,
        '_blank',
        `closebuttoncaption=Cancel${windowOptions}`
      );

      return this._requestCredentialsViaPostMessage(popup);
    } else if (oAuthWindowType == 'sameWindow') {
      window.location.href = authUrl;
    } else {
      throw `Unsupported oAuthWindowType "${oAuthWindowType}"`;
    }
  }

  loadParams(): void {
    this._getAuthDataFromParams();
  }

  signOut(): Observable<Response> {
    let observ = this.delete(this._authOptions.apiSignOutPath);

    this._clearAuthData();

    console.log('sign out', this._authOptions.validateTokenFailedRedirect)
    if (this._authOptions.validateTokenFailedRedirect)
      this._router.navigate([this._authOptions.validateTokenFailedRedirect]);

    return observ;
  }

  validateToken(): Observable<Response> {
    let observ = this.get(this._authOptions.apiValidateTokenPath);

    observ.subscribe(
        res => this.atCurrentUserData = res.json().data,
        error => {
            if (error.status === 401 && this._authOptions.signOutFailedValidate) {
                this.signOut();
            }
        });

    return observ;
}


  updatePassword(updatePasswordData: UpdatePasswordData): Observable<Response> {
    let args: any;

    if (updatePasswordData.passwordCurrent == null) {
      args = {
        password: updatePasswordData.password,
        password_confirmation: updatePasswordData.passwordConfirmation
      }
    } else {
      args = {
        current_password: updatePasswordData.passwordCurrent,
        password: updatePasswordData.password,
        password_confirmation: updatePasswordData.passwordConfirmation
      };
    }

    if (updatePasswordData.resetPasswordToken) {
      args.reset_password_token = updatePasswordData.resetPasswordToken;
    }

    let body = JSON.stringify(args);
    return this.put(this._authOptions.apiUpdatePasswordPath, body);
  }

  resetPassword(resetPasswordData: ResetPasswordData): Observable<Response> {
    let body = JSON.stringify({
      email: resetPasswordData.email,
      redirect_url: this._authOptions.resetPasswordCallbackPath
    });

    return this.post(this._authOptions.apiResetPasswordPath, body);
  }

  //--------------------------------------------Private Methods---------------------------------------------------------

  private _processAuthDataChecking() {
    if (this._authOptions.authDataChecking) {
      this._authDataInterval = setInterval(() => {
        let authData: AuthData = {
          accessToken: this._authOptions.dataStorage.getItem('accessToken'),
          client: this._authOptions.dataStorage.getItem('client'),
          expiry: this._authOptions.dataStorage.getItem('expiry'),
          tokenType: this._authOptions.dataStorage.getItem('tokenType'),
          uid: this._authOptions.dataStorage.getItem('uid')
        };


        if (this._checkAuthData(authData) && this._authData != authData) {
          if (!this._authData) {
            this._loadAuthData();
          }
        }

        if (this._authData)
          if (!this._checkAuthData(authData) && this._authData != authData) {
            this._clearAuthData();
          }

      }, this._authOptions.authDataCheckingInterval);
    }
  }

  private _clearAuthData() {
    this._authOptions.dataStorage.removeItem('accessToken');
    this._authOptions.dataStorage.removeItem('client');
    this._authOptions.dataStorage.removeItem('expiry');
    this._authOptions.dataStorage.removeItem('tokenType');
    this._authOptions.dataStorage.removeItem('uid');

    this._authData = null;
    this._userData = null;
  }

  private _checkAuthData(authData: AuthData): boolean {
    if (
      authData.accessToken != null &&
      authData.client != null &&
      authData.expiry != null &&
      authData.tokenType != null &&
      authData.uid != null
    ) {
      if (this._authData != null)
        return authData.expiry >= this._authData.expiry;
      else
        return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }

  private _getAuthDataFromParams() {
    if (this._activatedRoute.queryParams)
      this._activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(queryParams => {
        let authData: AuthData = {
          accessToken: queryParams['token'] || queryParams['auth_token'],
          client: queryParams['client_id'],
          expiry: queryParams['expiry'],
          tokenType: 'Bearer',
          uid: queryParams['uid']
        };

        if (this._checkAuthData(authData))
          this._setAuthData(authData);
      });
  }

  private _getAuthDataFromStorage() {
    let authData: AuthData = {
      accessToken: this._authOptions.dataStorage.getItem('accessToken'),
      client: this._authOptions.dataStorage.getItem('client'),
      expiry: this._authOptions.dataStorage.getItem('expiry'),
      tokenType: this._authOptions.dataStorage.getItem('tokenType'),
      uid: this._authOptions.dataStorage.getItem('uid')
    };

    if (this._checkAuthData(authData))
      this._authData = authData;
  }

  private _getAuthHeadersFromResponse(data: any): void {
    let headers = data.headers;

    let authData: AuthData = {
      accessToken: headers.get('access-token'),
      client: headers.get('client'),
      expiry: headers.get('expiry'),
      tokenType: headers.get('token-type'),
      uid: headers.get('uid')
    };

    this._setAuthData(authData);
  }

  private _loadAuthData() {
    this._getAuthDataFromStorage();

    if (this._activatedRoute)
      this._getAuthDataFromParams();

    if (this._authData)
      this.validateToken();
  }

  private _setAuthData(authData: AuthData): void {
    if (this._checkAuthData(authData)) {
      this._authData = authData;
      this._authOptions.dataStorage.setItem('accessToken', authData.accessToken);
      this._authOptions.dataStorage.setItem('client', authData.client);
      this._authOptions.dataStorage.setItem('expiry', authData.expiry);
      this._authOptions.dataStorage.setItem('tokenType', authData.tokenType);
      this._authOptions.dataStorage.setItem('uid', authData.uid);
    }
  }

  //--------------------------------------------Path Constructors-------------------------------------------------------

  private _getApiPath(): string {
    let constructedPath = '';

    if (this._authOptions.apiPath != null)
      constructedPath += this._authOptions.apiPath + '/';

    return constructedPath;
  }

  private _getOAuthPath(oAuthType: string): string {
    let oAuthPath: string;

    oAuthPath = this._authOptions.oAuthPaths[oAuthType];
    if (oAuthPath == null)
      oAuthPath = `/auth/${oAuthType}`;

    return oAuthPath;
  }

  private _getOAuthUrl(oAuthPath: string, callbackUrl: string, windowType: string): string {
    let url: string;

    url = `${this._authOptions.oAuthBase}/${oAuthPath}`;
    url += `?omniauth_window_type=${windowType}`;
    url += `&auth_origin_url=${encodeURIComponent(callbackUrl)}`;

    return url;
  }

  //--------------------------------------------OAuth-------------------------------------------------------------------

  private _getAuthDataFromPostMessage(data: any): void {
    let authData: AuthData = {
      accessToken: data['auth_token'],
      client: data['client_id'],
      expiry: data['expiry'],
      tokenType: 'Bearer',
      uid: data['uid']
    };
    this._setAuthData(authData);
    this.validateToken();
  }

  private _requestCredentialsViaPostMessage(authWindow: any): Observable<any> {
    return Observable.create(windowObserver => {

      Observable.create(responseObserver => {
        let messageSubscription = Observable.fromEvent(window, 'message')
          .pluck('data')
          .filter(this._oAuthWindowResponseFilter)
          .subscribe(data => responseObserver.next(data));

        setInterval(() => {
          if (authWindow.closed) {
            messageSubscription.unsubscribe();
            responseObserver.complete();
          } else authWindow.postMessage('requestCredentials', '*');
        }, 1000)

      }).subscribe(
        data => {
          switch (data.message) {
            case 'deliverCredentials':
              this._getAuthDataFromPostMessage(data);
              windowObserver.next('ok');
              break;
            case 'authFailure':
              windowObserver.error('Произошла неизвестная ошибка');
              break;
          }
        },
        () => {
        },
        () => {
          windowObserver.complete()
        }
      );
    });
  }

  private _oAuthWindowResponseFilter(data: any): any {
    if (data.message == 'deliverCredentials' || data.message == 'authFailure')
      return data;
  }

  //--------------------------------------------HTTP Wrappers-----------------------------------------------------------
  get(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.request(this._mergeRequestOptionsArgs({
      url: this._getApiPath() + url,
      method: RequestMethod.Get
    }, options));
  }

  post(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.request(this._mergeRequestOptionsArgs({
      url: this._getApiPath() + url,
      method: RequestMethod.Post,
      body: body
    }, options));
  }

  put(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.request(this._mergeRequestOptionsArgs({
      url: this._getApiPath() + url,
      method: RequestMethod.Put,
      body: body
    }, options));
  }

  delete(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.request(this._mergeRequestOptionsArgs({
      url: this._getApiPath() + url,
      method: RequestMethod.Delete
    }, options));
  }

  patch(url: string, body: any, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.request(this._mergeRequestOptionsArgs({
      url: this._getApiPath() + url,
      method: RequestMethod.Patch,
      body: body
    }, options));
  }

  head(path: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.request({
      method: RequestMethod.Head,
      url: this._getApiPath() + path
    });
  }

  options(url: string, options?: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {
    return this.request(this._mergeRequestOptionsArgs({
      url: this._getApiPath() + url,
      method: RequestMethod.Options
    }, options));
  }

  request(options: RequestOptionsArgs): Observable<Response> {

    let baseRequestOptions: RequestOptions;
    let baseHeaders: { [key: string]: string; } = this._authOptions.globalOptions.headers;

    // Merge auth headers to request if set
    if (this._authData != null) {
      (<any>Object).assign(baseHeaders, {
        'access-token': this._authData.accessToken,
        'client': this._authData.client,
        'expiry': this._authData.expiry,
        'token-type': this._authData.tokenType,
        'uid': this._authData.uid
      });
    }

    baseRequestOptions = new RequestOptions({
      headers: new Headers(baseHeaders)
    });

    baseRequestOptions = baseRequestOptions.merge(options);

    let response = this._http.request(new Request(baseRequestOptions)).share();

    this._handleResponse(response);

    return response;
  }

  private _mergeRequestOptionsArgs(options: RequestOptionsArgs, addOptions?: RequestOptionsArgs): RequestOptionsArgs {

    let returnOptions: RequestOptionsArgs = options;

    if (options)
      (<any>Object).assign(returnOptions, addOptions);

    return returnOptions;
  }


  private _handleResponse(response: Observable<Response>): void {
    response.subscribe(res => {
      this._getAuthHeadersFromResponse(<any>res);
    }, error => {
      this._getAuthHeadersFromResponse(<any>error);
    });
  }

}
```

auth.model:

```
export interface LogInData {
  email: string;
  password: string;
}

export interface SignUpData {
  email: string;
  password: string;
  passwordConfirmation: string;
}

export interface GlobalOptions {
  headers?: {[key: string]: string;}
}

export interface AuthOptions {
  apiPath?: string;
  apiSignInPath?: string;
  signInPath?: string;
  signInRedirect?: string;
  dataStorage?: any;
  apiSignOutPath?: string;
  validateTokenFailedRedirect?: string;
  signOutFailedValidate?: boolean;
  signInStoredUrlStorageKey?: string,

  apiValidateTokenPath?: string;

  apiDeleteAccountPath?: string;
  apiRegisterAccountPath?: string;
  registerAccountCallbackPath?: string;

  apiUpdatePasswordPath?: string;
  apiResetPasswordPath?: string;
  resetPasswordCallbackPath?: string;

  oAuthBase?: string;
  oAuthPaths?: {[key: string]: string;};
  oAuthCallbackPath?: string;
  oAuthWindowType?: string;
  oAuthWindowOptions?: {[key: string]: string;};

  globalOptions?: GlobalOptions;

  authDataChecking?: boolean;
  authDataCheckingInterval?: number;

  userDataClass: any;
}

export interface AuthData {
  accessToken: string;
  client: string;
  expiry: string;
  tokenType: string;
  uid: string;
}

export interface UserData {
  user_id:        number;
  provider:       string;
  uid:            string;
  name:           string;
  nickname:       string;
  image:          any;
  email:          string;
}

export interface RegisterData {
  [key: string]: string;
}

export interface SignInData {
  login: string;
  email: string;
  password: string;
  userType?: string;
}

export interface UpdatePasswordData {
  password:               string;
  passwordConfirmation:   string;
  passwordCurrent?:       string;
  userType?:              string;
  resetPasswordToken?:    string;
}

export interface ResetPasswordData {
  email: string;
  userType?: string;
}
```

Comment: Are you using `Http` or `HttpClient`? What is the response from `result.json()` Try logging it to the `console` and check, If possible, consider creating a stackblitz.

Comment: @SiddAjmera I use `Http`. In general in the console the only thing that is output is an error. And if  add `console.log(photo)`, then the whole list is displayed on the image from the JSON.

Comment: Please consider creating a stackblitz if possible.

Comment: @SiddAjmera I'm sorry if I could add code to "Stackblitz" then I would add it, but my proxy blocks this one.

Comment: Please add implementation of your `AuthService` as well here.

Comment: @SiddAjmera Added the full AuthService code with the model

Comment: Also, your Photo model should be an interface instead of a Class. That's what Angular Style Guide Suggests.

Comment: @SiddAjmera I apologize, but I did not understand what you mean.

Answer (score 0):

If I get you right (don't know anything about rails), your photos get served via the rails app and you're using an Angular front end to display them. This gives you the error `GET http://localhost:4200/photos/original/missing.png 404 (Not Found)`.

As `localhost:4200` is the standard host for the Angular development server, it looks like you're requesting a photo with a relative url and thus they are called from the angular dev server.

So either make your photo url an absolute one (like `http://the-rails-host/photos/original/missing.png` instead of just `/photos/original/missing.png`) or add the photos to your angular assets.